# Angular load image from Backend .net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-material

Please help me angular fileuploading using reactive forms , I have two more controls had with it , let say it name and useraddress  in (app component) using .net core and display the same image 
in another component e.g. display component . Note the image should be stored in backend folder and image should not be blob type and image should be display using image url

Comment: Look into sending and loading based on base64. Look like you need to try it out yourself first.

Comment: How can I access images in angular using img [src] if images are stored not in assets folder but outside the angular project folder, lets say it as images are stored in .net core project inside images folder , do you know how to access these images dynmically using path

Comment: What you do is you send them with your backend to angular as a base64 string.
Your backend should be able to parse an image to a base64 and back.

Comment: I have got a solution which may be alternative , I have made a folder in another server which I can store only images and docs , so that everytime  I make post request , I first make a service call to backend to insert file into third server , after inserting in that server  , I have made it to return file path and filename , which I am making a service call to backend to  store fields such as name and email . so whenever I want to access , I just retrieve file path and  I am displaying it